# How do I create an interactive plot in python that generates a new plot depending on where i clicked?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, bokeh

I have sales data across stores, for each month and for different categories of products.

Say I have a heatmap of sales quantities across stores and months on either axes.

Now when I click on heatmap at a spot corresponding to a particular store and month, I need a new barplot generated which shows sales quantities of each category  in that month and store.

I have done something similar in SAS VA. I believe its called an interaction effect.

I have tried searching documentation of matplotlib and plotly didnt get anything useful yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how you could do this in Bokeh v1.1.0

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import TapTool, CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Row, ColorBar, LinearColorMapper, BasicTicker
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.transform import transform
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis256
import random

stores = ["store 1", "store 2", "store 3"]
months = ["january", "fabruary", "march"]
x = ["store 1", "store 2", "store 3", "store 1", "store 2", "store 3", "store 1", "store 2", "store 3"]
y = ["january", "january", "january", "fabruary", "fabruary", "fabruary", "march", "march", "march"]
colors = ["#0B486B", "#79BD9A", "#CFF09E", "#79BD9A", "#0B486B", "#79BD9A", "#CFF09E", "#79BD9A", "#0B486B" ]

p1 = figure(title = "Categorical Heatmap", tools = "tap", toolbar_location = None,
            x_range = stores, y_range = months)
p1.rect(x = x, y = y, color = colors, width = 1, height = 1)

categories = ['shoes', 'pants', 'suits']
category_sales = {}
for store in stores:
    category_sales[store] = {}
    for month in months:
        category_sales[store][month] = [random.choice([i for i in range(10000)]) for r in range(3)]

dummy_category_sales = [1000, 1100, 1200]
data = {'x': categories, 'y': dummy_category_sales}
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

p2 = figure(x_range = categories)
bars = p2.vbar(x = 'x', top = 'y', source = source, bottom = 0, width = 0.5)
bars.visible = False

code = '''if (cb_data.source.selected.indices.length > 0){
            bars.visible = true;
            selected_index = cb_data.source.selected.indices[0];    
            store = cb_data.source.data['x'][selected_index]
            month = cb_data.source.data['y'][selected_index]

            bars.data_source.data['y'] = category_sales[store][month]
            bars.data_source.change.emit(); 
        }'''

p1.select_one(TapTool).callback = CustomJS(args = dict(bars = bars, category_sales = category_sales), code = code)

plots = Row(p1, p2)
show(plots)
```

Result:

[image]